# Find the maximum element which is common in two arrays?

Tags: algorithm

Given two arrays, how to find the maximum element which is common to both the arrays?

I was thinking of sorting both the arrays(n log n) and then perform the binary search of every element from one sorted array(starting from larger one) in another array until match is found.

eg:

```
a = [1,2,5,4,3]
b = [9,8,3]

Maximum common element in these array is 3
```

Can we do better than n log n?

Comment: Not that it helps the overall complexity, but in your last step a linear search, with an early-out when you find a too-small value, would probably be faster than a binary search. Each time you could restart it from where you left off last time (not from the beginning), because the value you're looking for is less than the last value you looked for. So the total time spent searching is O(the size of "another array"), split unevenly between the elements of "one sorted array". You could also do interpolation searches and suchlike.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With some extra space you could hash in 1 array, then do a contains on each element of the other array keeping track of the biggest value that returns true.  Would be O(n).

Comment: Just beat me to it. Of course, if hashes are not unique, the time complexity could be a little higher (verifying that a hash match is an actual match would require a search)... if hashes are unique, you incur an O(n) storage cost.

Answer (score 7):

You can but using `O(N)` space.
Just go through the first array and place all elements in a `HashTable`. This is `O(N)`
Then go through the second array keeping track of the current maximum and checking if the element is in the `HashTable`. This is also `O(N)` .
So total runtime is `O(N)` and `O(N)` extra space for the `HashTable`

Example in Java:

```
public static int getMaxCommon(int[] a, int[] b){  
  Set<Integer> firstArray = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));  
  int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  
  for(Integer n:b){  
     if(firstArray.contains(n)){  
         if(currentMax < n){  
              currentMax = n  
         }
     }   
  }   
  return currentMax;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While it depends on the time complexities of the various operations in specific languages, how about creating sets from the arrays and finding the maximum value in the intersection of the two sets? Going by the time complexities for operations in Python, it'd be, on average, O(n) for the set assignments, O(n) for the intersections, and O(n) for finding the max value. So average case would be O(n).

However! Worst-case would be O(len(a) * len(b)) -> O(n^2), because of the worst-case time complexity of set intersections.

More info here, if you're interested: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the range of numbers that would be in your arrays, you could perform counting sort, and then perform the binary search like you wanted. This would yield O(n) runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
sort list1 in descending order
sort list2 in descending order
item *p1 = list1
item *p2 = list2
while ((*p1 != *p2) && (haven't hit the end of either list))
  if (*p1 > *p2)
    ++p1;
  else
    ++p2;
// here, either we have *p1 == *p2, or we hit the end of one of the lists
if (*p1 == *p2)
  return *p1;
return NOT_FOUND;
```

Comment: Is the `sort list1 in descending order` a `O(N)` operation?I don't think so.Unless you figured an `O(N)` sorting algorithm

Comment: Not unless you've discovered a new sorting algorithm. It's still O(n log n) for the sorting + O(N) for the scan = O(N log n) overall. I'm fairly sure you can't do better unless you can make certain assumptions about the order of the lists at the beginning.

Comment: The OP already knows that he can use sort as a pre-processing step at the cost of sorting. The OP is about an `O(N)` approach. If you sort it clearly is not, hence my comment about figuring a new sorting algo

Comment: @user384706 The OP says nothing about O(N), but simply asks whether we can do better than O(N log N). I think the hash and scan option mentioned in another answer is probably the best route, and can approach O(N), but hash collisions could, in pathological cases, still make it O(N log N).

Comment: "Is the sort a O(N) operation?" - it could be, via the (boringly pedantic) use of a binary radix sort on fixed-width numeric data.

Comment: @SteveJessop:Yes of course but only for specific kind of input data

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect, but a simple solution, O(len(array1) + len(array2))

```
import sys


def find_max_in_common(array1, array2):
    array1 = set(array1)
    array2 = set(array2)

    item_lookup = {}

    for item in array1:
        item_lookup[item] = True

    max_item = -sys.maxsize

    intersection = False

    for item in array2:
        if not item_lookup.get(item, None):
            continue
        else:
            intersection = True
            if item > max_item:
                max_item = item

    return None if not intersection else max_item
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using binary search (and invariants to "proof" correctness):

```py
from bisect import bisect_left

def findLargestCommon(nums0, nums1):
    # Find the largest common element of two sorted lists
    if not nums0 or not nums1:
        return None
    i = len(nums0) - 1
    j = len(nums1) - 1
    if nums0[i] == nums1[j]:
        return nums0[i]
    elif nums0[i] > nums1[j]:
        nums0, nums1 = nums1, nums0
        i, j = j, i
    
    while i >= 0 and j > 0:
        # nums0[i] < nums1[j]
        # look for nums0[i] in nums1[:j]
        jj = bisect_left(nums1, nums0[i], hi=j)
        if jj == j:
            # nums1[j-1] < nums0[i] < nums1[j]
            j -= 1
            # nums1[j] < nums0[i]
            nums0, nums1 = nums1, nums0
            i, j = j, i
            # nums0[i] < nums1[j]
        # (jj != j) and nums1[jj] >= nums0[i]
        elif nums1[jj] == nums0[i]:
            return nums0[i]
        else: # nums1[jj] > nums0[i]
            j = jj
            # nums0[i] < nums1[j]
    return None
```